# java depth web crawler issue

Tags: java, web-crawler

I am trying to create a web crawler that gets a URL, download its HTML source and save it, fetch the links on that HTML, and for every link extracted I should repeat the process.
The program should accept those arguments:

1. The maximal amount of different URLs to extract from the page
2. How deep the process should run
3. Boolean flag indicating cross-level uniqueness

For example: `

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            HtmlHandler htmlHandler = HtmlHandler.builder()
            .url("https://www.google.com")
            .amountOfUrls(5)
            .depth(Depth.TWO)
            .isUnique(true)
            .build();
           htmlHandler.crawlWebPages();
}`
```

The desired result from it would be:

1. save the HTML of the provided URL to: 0/www_google_com_html and fetch 5 unique URL's from the HTML
2. save the 5 HTML's from step 1 to: 1/www......  and fetch 5 unique URL's from each HTML
3. save the 25 HTML's from step 2 to 2/www...... and quit the program

I basically was able to make it work for depth 1 ( step 2) but I am not able to make the program work for depth 2 ( fetching the 25 HTML's)

this is the code that saves the HTML:

```
    private void downloadHtml(String url, Depth depth) {
    try {
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(url), new    File(StringHandler.createFileName(url, depth)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("error downloading html source file", e);
    }
}
```

this is the code that should fetch the URL's:

```
 private void getPageLinks(Depth depth)  {
    switch (depth) {
        case ZERO -> zeroDepthCrawling();
        case ONE -> oneDepthCrawling();
        case TWO -> twoDepthCrawling();
    }
}

private void twoDepthCrawling()  {
    oneDepthCrawling();
    for(String url : urlLinks){
        downloadHtml(url, Depth.TWO);
        System.out.println(url + " downloaded");
    }
}

private void oneDepthCrawling()  {
    zeroDepthCrawling();
    getUrls(this.url);
    for (String url : urlLinks) {
        downloadHtml(url, Depth.ONE);
        System.out.println(url + " downloaded");
        getUrls(url);
    }
}

private void zeroDepthCrawling() {
    downloadHtml(this.url, Depth.ZERO);
    System.out.println(url + " downloaded");
}

private void getUrls(String url)  {
        Document doc;
        int counter =0;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("couldn't fetch links");
        }
        Elements availableLinksOnPage = doc.select("a[href]");
        for (Element element : availableLinksOnPage) {
            if(counter <= amountOfUrls){
                if(!urlLinks.contains(element.absUrl("href"))){
                    urlLinks.add(element.absUrl("href"));
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Can anyone please help?
Thanks

Comment: Why does it not work, is there an exception? What happens in twoDepthCrawling?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.base/java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1584)
 at java.base/java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:1607)
 at utils.HtmlHandler.oneDepthCrawling(HtmlHandler.java:63)
 at utils.HtmlHandler.twoDepthCrawling(HtmlHandler.java:53)
 at utils.HtmlHandler.getPageLinks(HtmlHandler.java:48)
 at utils.HtmlHandler.crawlWebPages(HtmlHandler.java:32)
 at main.Main.main(Main.java:16)

Comment: this is the exception

Comment: I don't see any multithreaded code, but apparently, there are some threads involved.
Where do you initialize a HashMap? What if you try to use ConcurrentHashMap?

Comment: I am not using HashMap at all. I think it has something to do with the for loop. But anyway, I still think that the logic that I created here won't give me the 25 HTML sources I am looking for. This is where I am having troubles The part where I fetch 5 HTMLs from each url

Comment: urlLinks seems to be a HashMap

Comment: trust me it's not. it's a Set